# Hiding Ionic card if there is not data for that card

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building a pokedex and I am trying to hide a Ionic card if there is no previous or next revolutions.

For example: Bulbasaur has two next evolutions and no previous evolutions. I need to hide the card for previous evolutions or display a message in the card saying that this pokemon has no previous evolutions

My template looks like this:

```
     <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        Previous Evolutions
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let evolutions of pokemon.PreviousEvolutions">
              <img src="assets/images/{{evolutions.Number}}.png" style="width:30%; height:30%">        Name: {{evolutions.Name}}<br/> Number: {{evolutions.Number}}
            </ion-item>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      Next Evolutions
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let evolutions of pokemon.NextEvolutions">
                <img src="assets/images/{{evolutions.Number}}.png" style="width:30%; height:30%">        Name: {{evolutions.Name}}<br/> Number: {{evolutions.Number}}
              </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
"PreviousEvolutions": [
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "Name": "Bulbasaur"
    }
  ],

  "NextEvolutions": [
    {
      "Number": 3,
      "Name": "Venusaur"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Using NgIf works for hiding the ion-item but the header stays and if a pokemon has no evolutions then there will be a blank card which is what I'm trying to hide.

Answer (score 2):

Just use *ngIf by checking the length of **`pokemon.PreviousEvolutions`**

```
 <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        Previous Evolutions
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content *ngIf="pokemon.PreviousEvolutions.length >0">
          <ion-item *ngFor="let evolutions of pokemon.PreviousEvolutions">
              <img src="assets/images/{{evolutions.Number}}.png" style="width:30%; height:30%">        Name: {{evolutions.Name}}<br/> Number: {{evolutions.Number}}
            </ion-item>
      </ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-content *ngIf="pokemon.PreviousEvolutions.length === 0">
         <h1> No items </h1>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngIf to conditionally show certain elements

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let evolutions of pokemon.PreviousEvolutions" *ngIf="evolutions.length > 0">
    <img src="assets/images/{{evolutions.Number}}.png" style="width:30%; height:30%">        Name: {{evolutions.Name}}<br/> Number: {{evolutions.Number}}
            </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap them in `<ng-container>` which doesn't have DOM representation, but will allow you to show and hide with condition (when its content is empty, for example). Also you will avoid the manipulation the DOM inside the component class.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="pokemon.PreviousEvolutions">
  <ion-card> 
  ...
  </ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

and

```
<ng-container *ngIf="pokemon.NextEvolutions">
  <ion-card> 
  ...
  </ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use angular template for that matter:

```
<ion-row *ngIf="items else noItem">
  <ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let post of items | slice:0:limit">
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
       // card content
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

**Note:** pay attention to `else noItem` part
Then you add this:

```
<ng-template #noItem>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12">
        <ion-card class="welcome-card">
          <ion-card-content>
            You don't have any saved article try to add some and back again.
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
</ng-template>
```

Here I used `ng-template` with `#noItem` tag that I put in my loop code, now every time I have data in `items` will show them and if I don't have data I get second part with error message.

## Full code

```
<ion-row *ngIf="items else noItem">
  <ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let post of items | slice:0:limit">
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
       // card content
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ng-template #noItem>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12">
        <ion-card class="welcome-card">
          <ion-card-content>
            You don't have any saved article try to add some and back again.
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
</ng-template>
```

Hope it helps.

[Source](https://tjd-studio.com/blog/ionic-else-if-with-angular)